# stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php

This question has made me confused for days, I highly appreciate someone can help to sort it out.

I am running wp on apache+Ubuntu 14.04 64.

Someone has written me small php codes to display the coming url and match/display keyword from a text file (saying aaa.txt, not database involved).

The codes are "clever", but with some php errors. But I cannot correct it:

> Warning: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   {edited}.php(373) : eval()'d code on line 15

It seems `if (0 === strpos($host, $suffix)) {` is not correct, but I am a newbie, how to change it?

Here are the codes:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
@$cnText = file_get_contents('aaa.txt');
$cnText = str_replace('?', '', $cnText);
$cnText = preg_split('/\n|\r\n/', $cnText);
foreach ($cnText as $text) {
    $pos = strpos($text, ' ');
    $cnText[substr($text, 0, $pos)] = trim(substr($text, $pos));
}
$host = strrev(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
$domain = null;
$domainSuffix = array('.com.cn','.net.cn','.org.cn','.gov.cn','.com','.cn','.net','.cc','.org','.info','.biz','.tv','.guru');
$keyword = array();
foreach ($domainSuffix as $suffix) {
    $suffix = strrev($suffix);
if (0 === strpos($host, $suffix)) {
        $host = explode('.', substr($host, strlen($suffix)));
        $keyword[0] = strrev($host[0]);
        if(0 === strpos($keyword[0], 'xn--')) {
            require_once('idna_convert.class.php');
            $IDN = new idna_convert();
            $keyword[0] = $IDN->decode($keyword[0]);
        }
        $domain = $keyword[0] . strrev($suffix);
    }
     }
if (!empty($domain)) {
    $keywords = '';
    if (array_key_exists($domain, $cnText)) {
        $data = explode(' ', $cnText[$domain]);
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $value = trim($value);
                $keyword[$key] = $value;
                $keywords .= " $value";
            }
        }
    }
    echo $keywords;
?>
```

Comment: Look at the manual, http://php.net/strpos.

Comment: What are you expecting here: `$host = strrev(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));`

Comment: @Twisty The algorithm is comparing suffixes by reversing all the strings and then comparing prefixes. Unnecessarily complex, possibly, but not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the variable `$host` is being used for two different purposes at the same time. Primarily, it represents the hostname being processed (reversed, as part of somewhat over-engineered algorithm). But on this line the same variable name is used for an array:

```
$host = explode('.', substr($host, strlen($suffix)));
```

As soon as that line has run, all code expecting the previous meaning of the variable will either error or do the wrong thing.

You need to assign to a new variable name on that line, e.g. `$host_parts`, and work out which references to `$host` should actually be  to this array (`$host_parts`).

Note that this is largely a problem because the code is inside a loop. Looking at the algorithm, it's possible that it should stop after the first match, with an appropriately placed [`break` statement](http://php.net/break). Even so, reusing a variable name like this is generally a bad idea.